# Scikit-Learn/Python text classfication

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm working on text classification using Scikit-learn. I used Naives Bayes Classification to categorize the unstructured texts(Details column in the data-set below) to a set of labeled targets(Category) and I got the accuracy for test data, but can some one tell me how to print, to which category each unstructured text(from Details column in the data-set below) belong to?

Here is how my example data set looks like.

```
Details                                     |Category
-------------------------------------------------------------                                
Tanishq Jwellery Bangalore                  |jwellery
ODESK***BAL-28APR13                         |Others
AEGON RELIGARE LIFE IN                      |Others
INTERNET PAYMENT #999999                    |Transfer in for Card Payment
WWW.VISTAPRINT.IN                           |Others
Khazana Jwellery                            |jwellery
INTERNET PAYMENT #999999                    |Transfer in for Card Payment
Indian Oil                                  |Fuel
Touch foot wear                             |Clothing
```

## And here is a part of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
u_cols = ['Details','Category'] 
k= pd.read_csv('mydatset.csv', delimiter='\t',usecols = u_cols)
data=k[1:1000]
target_one=data['Category']
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

def train(classifier, X, y):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
    train_test_split(data.Details.values.astype('U'), target_one, 
    test_size=0.50, random_state=33)

    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print ("Accuracy: %s" % classifier.score(X_test, y_test))
    return classifier

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

trial1 = Pipeline([('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer()),
                 ('classifier', MultinomialNB())])

train(trial1, data.Details.values.astype('U'), target_one)
```

Comment: Please dont change the data sample to image. How are we able to copy then?

Comment: Okay I'm sorry sir, this was my first question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the returned classifier to some object and then call predict() on it.
Something like this:

```
trained_clf = train(trial1, data.Details.values.astype('U'), target_one)

predictions = trained_clf.predict(unstructured_data.Details.values.astype('U'))
```

Update:-
If you are talking about the accuracy inside the train() function, then you can print the predicted categories with the following:

```
def train(classifier, X, y):
    ...
    ...
    print ("Accuracy: %s" % classifier.score(X_test, y_test))
    print ("Predictions: %s" % classifier.predict(X_test)


    return classifier
```

Comment: I'm able to print the accuracy but not the category to which each text(Details column) belong to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but the accuracy part is already working. I meant if i explicitly pass a row for cross validating to which category the text in the detail column belong to,how would i check it?

Comment: @Vichu I added the line `print ("Predictions: %s" % classifier.predict(X_test)` which will print the predictions of your test data? Do you have any other data that you want to predict, then follow my original code above.